# MYSQL Current_Date

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Есть строчка из триггера:

```
SET NEW.`course` = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1-(substr(NEW.`group_code`, instr(NEW.`group_code`, '-')+1, 2)+2000);
```

Так я определяю курс студента. Но разумеется считает некорректно, нужно чтобы считало с первого сентября, а не с нового года.. На вход подается число 16, 17 или 18.

Comment: Сделайте `current_date() - interval 9 month`. ну или +3 месяца, но не добавляйте 1 к году

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо!